# Как узнать, изменлся ли столбец expiry_date в таблице пользователей?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Я столкнулся с очень специфической задачей с Oracle.
Мне нужно доказать, что значения в столбце `expiry_date` таблицы `dba_users` не были изменены в определенный период времени (*в течении последних выходных*).

У меня нет большого опыта общения с Oracle, по этому я не уверен, но кажется что функция под названием "audit" отключена.

Итак, мне нужна любая возможность проверить, были изменения полей в указанной таблице. Я уже пытался проанализировать таблицу `user_sessions` (хотел проверить наличие сессий в течение рассматриваемого периода), но не смог получить точный ответ.

Comment: `dba_users.expiry_date`  нельзя изменить напрямую, т.к это виртуальная колонка. Она может измениться в результате ´alter user ...` или в случае, если пароль истёк. Уточните,  что конкретно нужно узнать, изменял ли кто-то пользователя?

Comment: Да, если я узнаю изменял-ли кто-то пользователей, это решит и мой вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Включен ли аудит, можно узнать так:

```
show parameters audit_trail

NAME        TYPE   VALUE 
----------- ------ ----- 
audit_trail string DB
```

Если БД создавалась с помощью DBCA, то это стандартное значение параметра по умолчанию.

> Directs audit records to the database audit trail (the SYS.AUD$ table), except for records that are always written to the operating system audit trail. Use this setting for a general database for manageability.

На таблице `SYS.AUD$` существует ряд представлений (`dba_audit_(trail|object)`).
Например, следующая команда принудит пользвателя изменить пароль и содаст новую аудит запись:

```
alter user hr password expire;

select os_username, username, userhost, timestamp, obj_name, action_name  
from dba_audit_trail where action_name = 'ALTER USER';

OS_USERNAME  USERNAME     USERHOST     TIMESTAMP           OBJ_NAME ACTION_NAME                 
------------ ------------ ------------ ------------------- -------- ----------------------------
oracle       SYSTEM       dbsrv        2013-06-22 13:41:13 HR       ALTER USER                  
ME           ME           clnthost     2020-06-26 17:54:14 HR       ALTER USER
```